# Method 'add' in COM object of class 'Documents' returned error code 0x800A175D (<unknown>) which means: <unknown>

Tags: com, dynamics-ax-2012

[image]

I am trying to open word Template from AX 2012 Reports. It works fine in the env I have developed but when I try to execute the same from different login I face the "COM error"

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can always find help for these mysterious Office error codes by decoding the error code.  COM error codes contain three major parts:

- the top 4 bits indicate the severity of the error.  8 means "warning", one you can't ignore
- the next 12 bits is the facility code, the origin of the error.  10 means "automation"
- the lower 16 bits is the internal error code, the one that you really care about.

Switch your calculator to hex mode, 0x175d is error code 5981.  Now turn to Google and query "word error 5981".

Lots of good hits, you can read them at your leisure.  But clearly there's a problem with macros on that machine.  Best left to the IT staff at your site, use superuser.com if you need more help with that.

Comment: thanks for the information... about the error, i have restarted the machine couple of times, seems has resolved the issue.